# Every time I start typing a URL in chrome it suggest a wrong URL

Tags: google-chrome

I want to ask if someone knows how to avoid this

When I open the browser and I start typing a URL like

```
www.youtube
```

Google Chrome suggest a path that I have visited once, but that I do not want to go there every time

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight an auto-suggestion entry in the Omnibox. Then, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> will make Chrome forget it.